# Yield and do operations on each 3 rows of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have this DataFrame, and would like to yield slices of 3 rows, returning a new DateFrame with all those 3 rows sets aggregated to one containing the highest date, the lowest open, highest high, and last close.

```
       date        open        high         low       close        
0    1498907700  0.00010020  0.00010020  0.00009974  0.00010019  
1    1498908000  0.00010010  0.00010010  0.00010010  0.00010010  
2    1498908300  0.00010010  0.00010010  0.00009957  0.00009957     
3    1498908600  0.00009957  0.00009957  0.00009957  0.00009957  
4    1498908900  0.00010009  0.00010009  0.00009949  0.00009959  
5    1498909200  0.00009987  0.00009991  0.00009956  0.00009956  
...
789
```

Can I do sort of a groupby and apply a function on all those slices to yield a new DataSet?

The output DataSet should look like this :

```
       date        open        high         low       close        
0   1498908300  0.00010010  0.00010020  0.00009957  0.00009957  
1   1498909200  0.00009957  0.00010009  0.00009949  0.00009956  
...
789
```

If the rows number are not a multiple of 3 I'd like to have the orphans processed in the first set of 3 rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use groupby and aggregate

```
df.groupby(df.index//3).agg({'date': 'max', 'open': 'min', 'high': 'max', 'low': 'min','close': 'last'})
```

You get

```
    date        open        high        low         close
0   1498908300  0.00010010  0.00010020  0.00009957  0.00009957
1   1498909200  0.00009957  0.00010009  0.00009949  0.00009956
```

Comment: I edited my question. I need 'slices' of 3 rows aggregated to one in a new DataFrame with the operations I want (highest date, lowest low etc...)